# Pulling up the React Native menu in Android

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to pull up the React Native menu in Android on MacOS.

I am pressing CMD + M, and all it does is bring up a green triple circle icon.

[image: green triple circle]

I have also tried typing this in terminal:

```
adb shell input keyevent 82
```

No change.

Is there a way to bring this up? I am able to bring it up on iOS with CMD + D easily enough.

Answer (score 0):

This was due to the build being in release mode